# MovieClipSWFLoader autoplays against my wishes, but only on slow connections

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have an app that loads some XML, and sets up kind of a slideshow, where each slide can contain several assets, such as images and SWFs. When I load everything from `localhost` directly (served through Apache), the SWFs does not autoplay, but if I use Charles to throttle the speed to localhost, it starts playing before the SWF finishes loading, and before the slide containing the SWF is visible.

I'm creating my loader with

```
var loader:MovieClipSWFLoader = new MovieClipSWFLoader();

loader.smoothBitmapContent = true;
loader.autoLoad     = true;
loader.scaleContent = false;
loader.trustContent = true;
loader.autoStop     = true;
loader.maintainAspectRatio = true;
loader.showBusyCursor = false;
loader.x            = data.@posX;
loader.y            = data.@posY;
loader.width        = data.@width;
loader.height       = data.@height;
loader.source       = (new URLRequest(data.@url)).url; // Using URLRequest because data contains relative URLs, and the loader doesn't like that (thinks it's a path maybe?)
```

where `data` is a short XML fragment containing what the application needs to know. An example is `<swf posX="10" posY="50" width="100" height="100" url="swfs/1.swf"/>`

This particular SWF has a sound that plays in frame 9, and that ends up playing in the background before the SWF is supposed to be visible on stage. It works as it's supposed to when the app gets around to displaying the SWF no matter how quickly the SWF loads.

I've also tried setting `autoLoad` to false and calling `load()` manually, but it still happens. As well as calling `gotoAndStop(1)` or `gotoFirstFrameAndStop()` without any effect.

When adding some `trace`-calls to the events that fire, I get `Event.OPEN`, `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`, `Event.INIT` and then sometime in between the rest of the `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` events, it plays, before finishing with `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS` and `Event.COMPLETE`.

The app is compiled with Flex 4.6 and tested with Flash Player 11.7.700.169

Comment: Noticed that Flash Player 11.8 is the newest version available. Upgraded, and it's still an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't always control the SWF, Ribs' answer won't always work, but for those I create myself, I plan on adding similar code just to be extra careful.

I managed to get it working by adding `gotoFirstFrameAndStop()` to every single event listener, and when that worked, removing one by one until I had only the ones really needed.

For anyone else encountering the same, I added

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.INIT, stopAutoplayingSWF);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, stopAutoplayingSWF);

private function stopAutoplayingSWF(e:Event):void
{
  (e.currentTarget as MovieClipSWFLoader).gotoFirstFrameAndStop();
}
```

The last on `Event.COMPLETE` might not be needed, since the SWF started playing before it fired, but it doesn't appear to hurt.

Answer (score 1):

In the SWF being loaded, place a stop on the first frame.  In your onLoadComplete function, call an init() function on the loaded swf.  In that function you would tell the loaded swf to play, or gotoAndPlay( 'label' or frame number ).

Or, in the SWF being loaded, add an AddedToStage event listener and call the init() function when that event executes:

```
if( stage )
{
    init();
}
else
{
    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );
}

function onAdded( evt:Event ):void
{
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );

    init();
}

function init():void
{
    // start your loaded swf playing or doing something
}
```

Comment: That's sometimes possible, but what if I didn't always create the SWF that gets loaded? Sometimes I'm just handed one, and would like to avoid recreating it

Comment: you could try calling stop() or gotoAndStop(1) when the swf loads, but if what you are saying about the swf playing before the onComplete fires is accurate, you might be out of luck.  You need to stop the swf from playing, which can only happen if you can control it before it starts doing its own thing.